# Program starts before it's piped into

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, zsh, pipeline

```
man -k . | fzf -e --tiebreak=begin | awk '{print $1}' | xargs man -Tpdf | zathura -
# searches for a man page and then outputs it as pdf to zathura
```

This is the command , it works great , other than zathura starting blank while it waits for stdin to give it input. It is really annoying having to change focus from zathura back to the terminal
and then back to zathura.

I am fairly new to scripting so i though that there might be a way around this that i just don't know about.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: The programs run in their own separated processes. The shell sets up the pipes and starts the processes. It can not know whether one of the processes already started to fill the pipe. The best you could do is to write a wrapper around zathura, which consumes its stdin and stores it internally, and as soon as it gets something on stdin, starts zathura and passes the input to zathura.

Comment: Why don't you separate completely **generating** a PDF and **looking** at it? The problem is that zathura seems to do both. You could have instead a program which just **creates** a PDF and if the file is completely created, start your PDF viewer. You can bundle these two steps into a single script.

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" my problem , I redirected output to my /tmp/ directory and then had zathura read from there  . I also put it all in a script .

```
   #!/bin/sh
   d=$(date +'%M_%S');
   man -k . | fzf -e --tiebreak=begin | awk '{print $1}' | xargs man -Tpdf > /tmp/man_${d};
   zathura /tmp/man_${d} 2> /dev/null &
```